# Animation plays for one frame, then back to blend tree locomotion. ONLY ON AN OBJECT

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, raycasting

I am trying to make a game like Dark Souls where there is a character who can roll and sprint. After implementing fall mechanics using a ray cast (if no ground detection fall ; if already falling then play animation) [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lw5Tv.png)

This was to stop player from being able to walk around while in the air... say he walked off the edge and gravity is slowly drifting him down.

While he is drifting down and able to still move around, he can roll and back step just fine (he is supposed to be falling). Though when he lands on any object, he will not be able to roll or back step. just walk around and sprint (locomotion blend tree) Same problem as the next paragraph

when moving the isInAir variable=true, outside an if statement but still* inside an else block who is making sure that the player is falling or not. then the falling animation will work.
Falling animation works, great! but now im on an Object where I cannot complete the animation.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YonLi.png)

BY THE WAY -- crossFade is set to zero (inside the animationHandler.PlayTargetAnimation function)  to get this far, or else my animation frame will freeze on the locomotion blend tree while still being able to move around and not roll (not even cover the distance of one)

[STUCK ON THIS FRAME IF I TRY TO ROLL WHILE ON THE GROUND. I CAN WALK AROUND BUT ROLLING FREEZES ME IN LOCOMOTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Z1jm.png)

Console logs the target animation and if player is falling. Both are accurate...

**TLDR -- Player cannot finish animation when on top of any object**

ANIMATIONS
[ANIMATIONS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ycRK.png)

SCRIPTS
[SCRIPTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6z2G.png)

This is actually from a video tutorial series and this code is verbatim yet not working... Other than some logs and the change in assigning isInAir's placement, its the same code.
Reference: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD_vBJjpCwJtrHIW1SS5_BNRk6KZJZ7_d

**I COMMENTED OUT THIS FUNCTION ENTIRELY AND NOW I FALL DOWN AT A SLOW SPEED WITH NO ANIMATION BUT AT LEAST I CAN ROLL ON SURFACE!**

```
    public void HandleFalling(float delta , Vector3 moveDirection)
    {
        
        playerManager.isGrounded = false;
        RaycastHit hit;
        Vector3 origin = myTransform.position;
        origin.y += groundDetectionRayStartPoint;



        //IF SOMETHING IS DIRECTLY IN FRONT OF YOU, YOURE NOT MOVING
        if (Physics.Raycast(origin , myTransform.forward , out hit ,0.6f))
        {
            moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
        }



        if(playerManager.isInAir)
        {
            rigidbody.AddForce(-Vector3.up * fallSpeed);
            rigidbody.AddForce(moveDirection * fallSpeed / 10f );
        }

        Vector3 dir = moveDirection;
        dir.Normalize();
        origin =  origin + dir * groundDirectionRayDistance;
        targetPosition = myTransform.position;

        //DEBUGGER
        Debug.DrawRay(origin , -Vector3.up * minimumDistanceToBeginFall, Color.red , 0.1f , false);

        //grounded
        if (Physics.Raycast(origin , -Vector3.up , out hit , minimumDistanceToBeginFall , ignoreForGroundCheck)) 
        {
            

            normalVector = hit.normal;
            Vector3 tp = hit.point;
            playerManager.isGrounded = true;
            targetPosition.y = tp.y;

            if (inAirTimer > 0.5f)
            {
                Debug.Log("you were in the air for " + inAirTimer);
                animatorHandler.PlayTargetAnimation("Unarmed-Land" , false);
                inAirTimer = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                animatorHandler.PlayTargetAnimation("Locomotion" , false);
                inAirTimer = 0;
            }

            playerManager.isInAir = false;


        }
        else //falling
        {
            Debug.Log("falling");
            
            playerManager.isInAir = true; //added to fix fall animation bug   *******************


            if (playerManager.isGrounded)
            {
                playerManager.isGrounded = false;
            }
            
            
            if (playerManager.isInAir == true)
            {
               if (playerManager.isInteracting == false)
               {
                   animatorHandler.PlayTargetAnimation("Falling" , true);
               }
               
               Vector3 vel = rigidbody.velocity;
               vel.Normalize();
               rigidbody.velocity = vel * (movementSpeed/2);


                // if commented from the top and uncommented here, then rolls work but fall doesnt *******************
                //    playerManager.isInAir = true; 

                //When player is touching ground no matter what is commented out from above, PLAYER CANNOT ROLL WHILE TOUCHING GROUND

            }
        }

        if (playerManager.isGrounded)
        {
            if (playerManager.isInteracting || inputHandler.moveAmount > 0  )
            {
                myTransform.position = Vector3.Lerp(myTransform.position , targetPosition , Time.deltaTime);
            }
            else
            {
                myTransform.position = targetPosition;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Maybe if your using CrossFade it has a very long exit time? a typo float without the decimal?

Comment: @akaBase hey thank you so much for commenting, I have commented out crossFade and now I can walk around but i cannot roll/backstep. Is there any alternatives to Crossfade or maybe im using it wrong?   

anim.CrossFade(targetAnim , 0.2f);

Comment: @akaBase so i changed the .02 in the crossfade into .005 and now the roll animation runs for a split second. Sorry I really dont know how to code in unity but I am learning. IDK what CrossFade even does other than transition my animation magically

Comment: Have you set them to loop?

Comment: @akaBase So now cross fade is set to zero inside a function that will be called in update to "Play target animation"  but after some clever console logs , i have noticed that the animation will play but automatically set the timer back to zero which will make the animation switch back to walk/run/sprint (locomotion blend tree)

Comment: Ok so this is going to be long for a comment but i'll try. It sounds like you are trying to Crossfade to every animation/blendtree instead of using parameters and letting an animation controller take care of the transitions. Here is a simple animation controller I am using atm [Screenshot](https://prnt.sc/vcnccd) and here is the AnimationManager script that deals with the parameters [Screenshot](https://prnt.sc/vcneqe) And then use those white arrow transitions to tune the transitions.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to help me. I have updated the question description with pictures and a clear description of what is going on (i hope) Again, Thank you!

Comment: This `"and the change in assigning isInAir's placement"` and your explaination makes me think that your rig doesn't know when it is in the air and when it isn't and a bool set to allow normal moves isn't as it should be. and possibly missing an invert with a `!`

Comment: commenting out the whole handle falling function and taking it out of the update method allows me to roll on surface.

HandleFalling() will send a raycast down from the center of the player to the floor. and if no floor, play falling animation. Issue is that when there is a floor i need it to not run

Comment: @akaBase I have come to the conclusion that my rayCast is not working properly and I made a copy so i can proceed on one without any level design that allows me to fall... Ill add the code to the function about (its called in the update function insde playerHandler)

Comment: It's hard to know whats going on with your code due to it using variables from other classes, one thing i will say though is that it looks overcomplicated. I suggest having a `GroundCheck` method and a seperate `Falling` method which you use if the ground check fails, also I don't see the `float delta` being used

Comment: @akaBase I FOUND A SOLUTION! I want you to know that you were the only one that helped me not even contacting the video makers discord gave me a clear answer. WELL remember how i said that the animation only played for one frame then back to locomotion (walk/run/sprint)? well i found where it was set and played, made an if statement to check the roll timer... if roll timer greater than 0.14 play locomotion. idk what happened pragmatically tbh. it works though!

Comment: Please make sure to use the correct tags. Your code is in `c#` **not** in `unityscript` which is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like language used in previous Unity versions and is long deprecated by now.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, inside my handle falling function, the ground detection worked like a charm but the locomotion would play if im grounded right away. An if statement to check roll timer worked.

**THIS IS THE FUNCTION WHICH CAUSED THE PROBLEM**

```
public void HandleFalling(float delta , Vector3 moveDirection) //bugged function, commented out in PlayerManager.Update()
    {
        
        playerManager.isGrounded = false;
        RaycastHit hit;
        Vector3 origin = myTransform.position;
        origin.y += groundDetectionRayStartPoint;



        //IF SOMETHING IS DIRECTLY IN FRONT OF YOU, YOURE NOT MOVING
        if (Physics.Raycast(origin , myTransform.forward , out hit ,0.6f))
        {
            moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
        }



        if(playerManager.isInAir)
        {
            rigidbody.AddForce(-Vector3.up * fallSpeed);
            rigidbody.AddForce(moveDirection * fallSpeed / 4.5f );
        }

        Vector3 dir = moveDirection;
        dir.Normalize();
        origin =  origin + dir * groundDirectionRayDistance;
        targetPosition = myTransform.position;

        //DEBUGGER
        Debug.DrawRay(origin , -Vector3.up * minimumDistanceToBeginFall, Color.red , 0.1f , false);

        //grounded
        if (Physics.Raycast(origin , -Vector3.up , out hit , minimumDistanceToBeginFall , ignoreForGroundCheck)) 
        {

            normalVector = hit.normal;
            Vector3 tp = hit.point;
            playerManager.isGrounded = true;
            targetPosition.y = tp.y;

            if (inAirTimer > 0.5f)
            {
                Debug.Log("you were in the air for " + inAirTimer);
                animatorHandler.PlayTargetAnimation("Unarmed-Land" , false);
                inAirTimer = 0;
            }
            else
            { //SOLUTION TO THE ISSUE!!!!
                // Debug.Log(inputHandler.RollInputTimer);
                if(inputHandler.RollInputTimer > 0.19){
                    animatorHandler.PlayTargetAnimation("Locomotion" , false);
                    inAirTimer = 0;
                }

                
                // animatorHandler.PlayTargetAnimation("Locomotion" , false);
                // inAirTimer = 0;
            }

            playerManager.isInAir = false;


        }
        else //falling
        {
            Debug.Log("falling");
            
            playerManager.isInAir = true; //added to fix fall animation bug   *******************


            if (playerManager.isGrounded)
            {
                playerManager.isGrounded = false;
            }
            
            
            if (playerManager.isInAir == true)
            {
               if (playerManager.isInteracting == false)
               {
                   animatorHandler.PlayTargetAnimation("Falling" , true);
               }
               Vector3 vel = rigidbody.velocity;
               vel.Normalize();
               rigidbody.velocity = vel * (movementSpeed/2);


                // if commented from the top and uncommented here, then rolls work but fall doesnt *******************
                //    playerManager.isInAir = true; 

                //When player is touching ground no matter what is commented out from above, PLAYER CANNOT ROLL WHILE TOUCHING GROUND

            }
        }

        if (playerManager.isGrounded)
        {
            if (playerManager.isInteracting || inputHandler.moveAmount > 0  )
            {
                myTransform.position = Vector3.Lerp(myTransform.position , targetPosition , Time.deltaTime);
            }
            else
            {
                myTransform.position = targetPosition;
            }
        }

    }
```